# Kubernetes yaml deployment - unable to create a symbolic link

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to make an nginx deployment and during the container creation, I want to create multiply symbolic links. But for some reason, it doesn't work and the container crashes.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tcc
    component: nginx
  name: tcc-nginx-deployment
  namespace: dev2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tcc
      component: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tcc
        component: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - |
                ln -s /shared/apps/ /var/www
                rm -r /etc/nginx/conf.d
                ln -s /shared/nginx-config/ /etc/nginx/conf.d

        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /shared
          name: efs-pvc
      volumes:
      - name: efs-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: tcc-efs-storage-claim
```

Comment: any error messages you can share?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor yes answer from Mikolaj S. has fixed all me problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is not running, because after the `command` block is executed, container is exiting, which is expected behaviour.

Instead of playing with symbolic links in `command` in yaml template (which is not the best practice solution), why just don't use solution builtin Kubernetes and do not use `command` block at all?

You should use [`subPath` which is designed to share directories from one volume for multiple, different directories on the single pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath):

> Sometimes, it is useful to share one volume for multiple uses in a single pod. The `volumeMounts.subPath` property specifies a sub-path inside the referenced volume instead of its root.

In your case, the deployment yaml should look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tcc
    component: nginx
  name: tcc-nginx-deployment
  namespace: dev2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tcc
      component: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tcc
        component: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /shared
          name: efs-pvc
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
          name: efs-pvc
          subPath: nginx-config
        - mountPath: /var/www
          name: efs-pvc
          subPath: apps
      volumes:
      - name: efs-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: tcc-efs-storage-claim
```

Also if you want to mount only config files for NGINX, you may use ConfigMap instead of volume - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078899/16391991) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

- That's because you are asking container just to create symbolic links. So once those
  symbolic links are created container is getting exited.
- To avoid that add `"nginx" "-g" "daemon off;"` as following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tcc
    component: nginx
  name: tcc-nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tcc
      component: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tcc
        component: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - |
                ln -s /shared/apps/ /var/www
                rm -r /etc/nginx/conf.d
                ln -s /shared/nginx-config/ /etc/nginx/conf.d
                "nginx" "-g" "daemon off;" ; # after creating above symbolic links it will start nginx daemon 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /shared
          name: efs-pvc
      volumes:
      - name: efs-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: tcc-efs-storage-claim
```